# What path am I missing in vscode web extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to add a basic vscode web extension by hosting it on GitHub. I have hosted the code [here](https://github.com/AdamRaichu/vscode-minecraft-lang/tree/5da927a0f42934119198182ec5141f2c676546d2), and am trying to run the following command to install in vscode.dev.

```
> Developer: Install Web Extension...
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdamRaichu/vscode-minecraft-lang/5da927a0f42934119198182ec5141f2c676546d2/
```

However when I do, I get the following error.

```js
[2022-10-27 11:48:07.683] [window] [info] Installing extension: adamraichu.minecraft-lang
[2022-10-27 11:48:07.954] [window] [info] Request to 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdamRaichu/vscode-minecraft-lang/5da927a0f42934119198182ec5141f2c676546d2/package.nls.json' failed with status code 404
[2022-10-27 11:48:07.960] [window] [error] Error while installing the extension: adamraichu.minecraft-lang
[2022-10-27 11:48:07.965] [window] [error] The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined: Error: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at h (https://main.vscode-cdn.net/stable/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.js:78:11422)
    at Object.join (https://main.vscode-cdn.net/stable/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.js:78:18753)
    at h.joinPath (https://main.vscode-cdn.net/stable/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.js:83:9376)
    at C.joinPath (https://main.vscode-cdn.net/stable/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.js:84:6477)
    at K.toWebExtension (https://main.vscode-cdn.net/stable/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.js:3241:118766)
    at async K.addExtension (https://main.vscode-cdn.net/stable/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.js:3241:114719)
    at async u.doRun (https://main.vscode-cdn.net/stable/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.js:3242:7677)
```

**What path am I missing?**

*Note that trying to open any of these links from the log gets an error.*

```xml
<Error>
  <Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
  <Message>The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:50ecf237-701e-00a5-121b-eadf11000000 Time:2022-10-27T15:50:04.6433646Z</Message>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding `browser` to my package.json, with a path to a typescript file. This in turn showed me other missing things, but this fixed my problem.